# why MSE will be high when I inverse data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression

I make a regression model to predict force plate using plantar pressure. I am trying to use CNN model in this case. I have 2 different datasets, dataset A (force plate data) and dataset B (plantar pressure data). then before training the data I normalize the data first by using minmaxscaler(). during training I got good results and low MSE. then I tried to test the model and return the predicted data which was normalized to original data using the inverse function. after I inverted the data and I checked the MSE value again, the MSE value I got after inverting was very high. even though when viewed from the prediction results in my opinion very good. why is this MSE value suddenly so high.

the data look like below:

> Force Plate Data: [    4.46733,     4.39629,   -34.2351 , -4077.23   , -6206.81   ,
> -874.539  ]
>
> Force Plate Data Shape : (15000,6)
>
> SmartInsole Data: [  0.   0.   0.  13.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
> 15.  92.  60.   0.
> 36.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  62.  80.  58.  37.   0.   0.   0.
> 0.  40.  83.  72.  32.  22.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  98. 108.
> 74.  56.  30.  17.   0.   0.  44. 121. 127.  83.   0.   0.   0.   0.
> 0.   3.  83.  64.  63.  63.  77.  70.  43.  55. 115. 138. 144. 137.
> 0.   0.   0.   0.  66. 107. 127. 146. 150.  52.   0.   0.   0. 129.
> 133.  18.   0.   0.   0.]
>
> SmartInsole Data Shape : (15000,89)

here my model code:

```
## Load Data
Insole = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min1_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.array(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('1225_Rwalk10min.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx','Fy','Fz','Mx','My','Mz']
selected_df = df[columns]
FPDatas = selected_df[:15000]

label = pd.read_csv('label.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
labelData =  np.array(label).astype('float32')

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:15000]).astype('float32')
FPData = np.array(FPDatas).astype('float32')

Label = np.array(labelData[:15000]).astype('float32')

SIlabeled = np.concatenate((Label, SmartInsole), axis=1)
SIlabeled = np.array(SIlabeled).astype('float32')
## End Load Data

# Data Normalization
minInsole = SIlabeled.min()
maxInsole = SIlabeled.max()
xscale = (SIlabeled - minInsole) / ( maxInsole - minInsole )

FPmax = []
FPmin = []
yscale = []

for i in range(0,6):
    minFP = FPData[:,i].min()
    maxFP = FPData[:,i].max()
    FPmin.append(minFP)
    FPmax.append(maxFP)

FPmin = np.array(FPmin)
FPmax = np.array(FPmax)

for i in range(0,6):
  scale = (FPData[:,i] - FPmin[i]) / ( FPmax[i] - FPmin[i] )
  yscale.append(scale)
yscale = np.array(yscale)
yscale = yscale.transpose()

#End Data Normalization

# Spliting Data
sample_size = xscale.shape[0]
time_steps  = xscale.shape[1]
input_dimension = 1

train_data_reshaped = xscale.reshape(sample_size,time_steps,input_dimension)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data_reshaped, yscale, test_size=0.20, random_state=2)
print(X_train.shape,X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape,y_test.shape)
#End Spliting Data

#Model Structure
model = Sequential(name="model_conv1D")

n_timesteps = train_data_reshaped.shape[1
n_features  = train_data_reshaped.shape[2]

model.add(Input(shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.002), metrics=['mse'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=200,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2)
#End Model Structure

#Evaluate Model
model.evaluate(train_data_reshaped, yscale)
ypred = model.predict(train_data_reshaped)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('Loss Result.png')

print('MSE: ',mean_squared_error(yscale, ypred))
print('RMSE: ',math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(yscale, ypred)))
print('Coefficient of determination (r2 Score): ', r2_score(yscale, ypred))


#Inverse
y_inverse = []
y_pred_inverse = []


for i in range(0,6):
  Y_inver =  yscale[0:15000, i]*( FPmax[i] - FPmin[i] )+FPmin[i]
  Pred_inver = ypred[0:15000, i]*( FPmax[i] - FPmin[i] )+FPmin[i]
  y_inverse.append(Y_inver)
  y_pred_inverse.append(Pred_inver)
y_inverse = np.array(y_inverse)
y_inverse = y_inverse.transpose()
y_pred_inverse = np.array(y_pred_inverse)
y_pred_inverse = y_pred_inverse.transpose()


print('MSE: ',mean_squared_error(y_inverse, y_pred_inverse))
print('RMSE: ',math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_inverse, y_pred_inverse)))
print('Coefficient of determination (r2 Score): ', r2_score(y_inverse, y_pred_inverse))

x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
x = np.arange(0,3000)*60/3000 
for i in range(0,6):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    # plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y_inverse[0:3000,i],color='red')
    plt.plot(x,y_pred_inverse[0:3000,i], markerfacecolor='none',color='green')
    plt.title('CNN Regression (Training Data)')
    if i < 3:
      plt.ylabel('Force/'+columns[i])
    else:
      plt.ylabel('Moment/'+columns[i])
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='best')
    plt.show()
#End Evaluate Model
```

the model loss:

[image]

the mse use the normalize data:

```
MSE:  0.00033982666
RMSE:  0.018434387873554003
Coefficient of determination (r2 Score):  0.9934412267882915
```

the mse after inverse data:

```
MSE:  711726.3
RMSE:  843.6387334042931
Coefficient of determination (r2 Score):  0.9934412272949391
```

the prediction result samples:
[image]
[image]

```
print("Real Value : ",y_inverse[51])
print("prediction Value : ",y_pred_inverse[51])
Real Value :  [    4.46733      4.39629    -34.235107 -4077.2305   -6206.8125
  -874.53906 ]
prediction Value :  [    6.6143274     5.6351166   -31.929413  -3412.164     -6177.2344
 -2047.6455   ]
```

how to make MSE value not change when the data is inverted?

Comment: I think you are doing the wrong process here. You should invert the data back to its original scale **after** predictions are made, not before predicting. Since your test data is scaled back to its original value, it is understandable why the MSE loss is high.

Comment: I think I do the correct process, if you think I doing wrong process,let me know in which line of code above

Comment: The inverse line `Y_inver =  yscale[0:15000, i]*( FPmax[i] - FPmin[i] )+FPmin[i]` and `print('MSE: ',mean_squared_error(y_inverse, y_pred_inverse))`. You shouldn't compare MSE or any loss on on two different scales. It's like comparing Apples vs Oranges. As a simple example, imagine you normalize people's height to values between 0-1 to stabilize your model, and you can imagine the loss would be skyrocket if you scale back to its original values.

Comment: the reason why I comparing the MSE using the scaling data and MSE use the scale back data. because when I look at the scale prediction, the prediction its very close to real value. but when I scale back the data  to the original data, then the prediction and the real value its not close enough.

Comment: you can she these **Real Value :  [    4.46733      4.39629    -34.235107 -4077.2305   -6206.8125
  -874.53906 ]
prediction Value :  [    6.6143274     5.6351166   -31.929413  -3412.164     -6177.2344
 -2047.6455   ]**

Comment: That is expected since they are two different scales. For example, if we take the height example above, consider one is 100cm and one is 150cm, using our max is 200cm. When scaling back to 0-1 by dividing the values by 200 cm, we have the first value is 0.5 and the second value is 0.75. This gives you the difference as 0.25, but in fact, the difference is 50cm.

Comment: so means the model problem?